# Why the span of $K$ equals $K$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given that $K$ is a vector subspace then $Sp(K)=K$.

Can you please explain why?

I understand that $K$ spans $Sp(K)$, that is with the set of vectors $K$, for example {$(1,0), (0,1)$} we can span $\mathbb{R^2}$. So if anything $K \subseteq Sp(K)$. But $Sp(K)$ contains infinite number of vectors spanned by $K$ so how $Sp(K)=K$?

Comment: I think I just understood. $K$ is the whole subspace it's not just {$(1,0),(0,1)$} so the span of the subspace is the subspace itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any subset $S$ of a vector space $V$, the span of $S$ is the smallest vector subspace of $V$ containing $S$. Therefore, if $S$ itself is a vector subspace of $V$, then the span of $S$ is $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of thinking about this is the following:

Remember that $Sp(K)$ is the set of all finite linear combinations of vectors in $K$. Since vector spaces are closed under linear combination, each element of $Sp(K)$ must also be in $K$; that is, $Sp(K)\subseteq K$. You're right that $K\subseteq Sp(K)$, so $Sp(K) = K$.